# Sublime Text 3へのYUI Compressorのインストール方法

Tags: javascript, java, sublimetext

WindowsでSublime Text 3というテキストエディタを使っています。
Javascriptのファイルをminify化するのに、Sublime Text 3からYUI Compressorを使いたいです。

Package Controlはインストール済みなのですが
「Package Control: Install Package」
をしても、Packageの選択肢に
YUI Compressorが表示されません

レポジトリから削除されてしまったっぽい？

JavaやYUI Compressor本体はインストール済みで
Windowsのコマンドプロンプトからは、min.jsが生成できます。

毎回コマンドを打ち込むのは効率が悪いので
なんとかSublime Text3から一発でmin.jsが作成できるようにしたいです。

どなたか
Sublime Text 3へのYUI Compressorのインストール方法につてご教授頂けないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Package Controlのページ](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/YUI%20Compressor)が存在するので、削除されてはいないようです。ただしページに「MISSING」とあるように、Package Controlから[GitHubリポジトリ](https://github.com/gabrielgisoldo/YUI-Compressor)のリリースを取得できないようです。

リポジトリをcloneして手動でビルドすれば使えるかもしれませんが、YUI Compressor自体かなり古いようですし、他のminifierを試してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: Package Controlに登録されているのが
https://github.com/leon/YUI-Compressor
というGitHubのリポジトリなのですが404 NotFoundになります

上記コメントで紹介いただいた
https://github.com/gabrielgisoldo/YUI-Compressor
を試してみました。

Sublimetextで
Package Contorl: Add Repository
から
https://github.com/gabrielgisoldo/YUI-Compressor
を追加。

Package Contorl: Install Package
に
YUI Compressor
が表示されるようになる。

インストールする。

ツール＞Build System
を
YUI Compressor
にしてBuildしてみる。
何もファイルが生成されない。

ビルドというのが何なのか分かっていません。
自力では無理そうなので別のものを探してみます。

Comment: SublimeText3にMinifyというプラグインを入れてみたのですが日本語部分が文字化けしてしまってダメでした。
SublimeText3からの呼び出しはあきらめて、コマンドプロンプトからYUI Compressorを呼び出す方法で妥協します。